# Solving equations by taking square roots

Tags: quadratics, radicals, factoring

I am confused with solving equations by taking square roots. I have a math problem below as an example of what I am confused with.

$12x^2-154=0$

So first I believe you are supposed to move the constant to one side so it would be

$12x^2=154 $

After that I believe we need to divide by $12$, however $154$ is not divisible by $12$ nor do any perfect squares fit. I am aware they both share the greatest common factor of $2$, however I am not sure what to do with that or if it is needed. I am not sure.

Comment: So, it's just $x = \pm \sqrt{154/12}$ or however you'd like to reduce that.

Comment: I also thought that but my teacher gave an answer key with the answer of ±3.58 and I am not sure how to get that

Comment: They are equivalent??

Answer (score 0):

You can work with fractions, I assume?
Of course, in this case, your solutions for $x$ cannot be of integers, as you have already noticed. However, you can always do:
$$12x^2=154$$
$$x^2=\frac{77}{6}$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt\frac{77}{6}$$

Comment: I also thought that but my teacher gave an answer key with the answer of ±3.58 and I am not sure how to get that

Comment: @JakeMiller by plugging into a calculator... to which I'd say $\pm\sqrt {\frac {77}{6}}$ is more precise.  But some would like you to "rationalize the denominator."  $\frac {\sqrt {77\cdot 6}}{6} = \frac {\sqrt {462}}{6}$

Comment: could I ask what it means and why you would rationalize the denominator and multiply 77 by 6?

Comment: Because a fractions value remains unchanged when the numberator and denominator are multiplied by the same (non-zero!) quantity. We choose a convenient quantity that simplifies work: In this case $\sqrt6$ fits the bill as we need to calculate a single square root, that too for a whole number.